# Insert is slow and not doing full batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

We have a table that is heavily written to, and is about to exceed the values allowed for the INT Identity PK column. I created a script to batch insert records into an exact copy of the table, but with the PK column as BIGINT. The PK is the only index/constraint on the new table, because I'm using it to identify records that need to be migrated.

It's running painfully slow, and it seems like every time I look at sp_who2 the process is suspended and has a CXPACKET or CXCONSUMER wait. The WAITFOR in the script is so other processes can commit transactions in between batches. When I calculate how many rows it's moving, it's doing less than (9k-13k) one (50k) batch a minute. It's currently 250M records into moving 2.6B and growing. Fortunately at the pace we write to the current table, we have a couple months before we're in real trouble, but at the pace its going, it seems tight. I've tried adjusting batch size, and MAXDOP, with no change in pace.

```
DECLARE @RowsMoved INT = 1
        , @IsOkToRun BIT = 1


WHILE @IsOkToRun = 1 AND @RowsMoved > 0
    BEGIN
        
         WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.125'

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NEWTrackingColumnChange ON

        BEGIN TRAN

        INSERT INTO dbo.NEWTrackingColumnChange(TrackingColumnChangeId
                                              , TableName
                                              , ColumnName
                                              , SessionId
                                              , StatementId
                                              , PrimaryKey
                                              , OldValue
                                              , NewValue
                                              , ContextReferenceId
                                              , ContextReferenceType
                                              , CreatorId
                                              , CreateDate
                                              )
        SELECT TOP 50000 TCC.TrackingColumnChangeId
                      , TCC.TableName
                      , TCC.ColumnName
                      , TCC.SessionId
                      , TCC.StatementId
                      , TCC.PrimaryKey
                      , TCC.OldValue
                      , TCC.NewValue
                      , TCC.ContextReferenceId
                      , TCC.ContextReferenceType
                      , TCC.CreatorId
                      , TCC.CreateDate
        FROM dbo.TrackingColumnChange AS TCC WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN dbo.NEWTrackingColumnChange AS NTCC ON NTCC.TrackingColumnChangeId = TCC.TrackingColumnChangeId
        WHERE NTCC.TrackingColumnChangeId IS NULL

        SET @RowsMoved = @@ROWCOUNT

        COMMIT TRAN

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NEWTrackingColumnChange OFF

        SELECT @IsOkToRun = CAST(PropertyValue AS BIT)
        FROM dbo.ConfigSettings 
        WHERE PropertyName = 'TCCTableMoveEnabled'

    END
```

Query plan XML too large to post here. It's viewable at:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk2AmefuT

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your slow-running query

Comment: Using `NOLOCK` for this feels like a problem; are you really happy with potentially (very) wrong data?

Comment: I think you'd do better if you went the following road: 1) Get min and max IDs from table. 2) Set current to MIN id 3) Loop and select from your source table where ID is between current and current + 50000 4) Advance current ID. This way, you don't waste too much time on LOJ which is probably not indexed correctly due to INT vs BIGINT columns. @ThomA, i thought NOLOCK was like the old Turbo button on 80486

Comment: Hi - is there a reason why you are copying the data to a new table, rather than just changing the datatype of the PK column (dropping the constraint before you make the change and then re-adding it)?

Comment: Similar to siggemannen thoughts, at the top of your loop, calculate `DECLARE @HighWaterMark INT = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(NTCC.TrackingColumnChangeId), 0) FROM NEWTrackingColumnChange AS NTCC`. Next, drop the `LEFT JOIN` and change the condition to `WHERE TCC.TrackingColumnChangeId > @HighWaterMark ORDER BY TCC.TrackingColumnChangeId`. You would need to start over to copy rows in ID order.

Comment: Another approach would be to (1) Restore a backup (to a different target DB) to get a clean, inactive copy of the source table. (2) Drop the PK and just alter (rebuild) that table in place using `ALTER TABLE NEWTrackingColumnChange ALTER COLUMN TrackingColumnChangeId BIGINT`. (Data and IDs will be preserved. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V3JFyREB).) (3) Copy that table using utilities to the existing database. (4) Sync up the latest data using your script. (5) Wait for your next maintenance window to do the final sync and rename operations.

Comment: Aside... `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NEWTrackingColumnChange ON` seems like a code smell. You can only set identity insert on for a single table at a time (per database), you probably need to ask why the target table has an identity column in the first place (as opposed to using just a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint).

Comment: @NickW, that kind of operation usually lock the table and might not even succeed due to time and log space it's taking, plus, he probably needs to drop the clustered index for that which is also sometimes not acceptable

Comment: I think I might try the suggestions of eliminating the join in favor of grabbing chunks of records by their PK value. The wait types are what threw me off. I thought I was having parallelism issues

Comment: The NOLOCK is ok, because records aren't updated, only inserted. Dirty data isn't a concern